# how best to use list of codes from sql query as input for another query

Tags: mysql

I have couple of SQL im trying to use together to generate a report showing the AVG amount for 2 fields for a given code that i want to extract from the other query.  So this query returns the list of codes

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  cc.code AS `CC Code`
FROM ds
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dd
    ON ds.dd_id = dd.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ii
    ON ds.ii_id = ii.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc
    ON ds.id = dcc.dos_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cc
    ON dcc.cpt_id = cc.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN bi
    ON ds.bi_id = bi.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cs
    ON bi.claim_status = cs.id
WHERE ii.company = "Alpha"
AND cs.status = "On HOLD"
AND dcc.amount_allowed > 0
```

this returns a list of about 25 unique codes.  i then run this one manually plugging in each of those to get the avg amounts for 2 fields that use that code.

```
SELECT
  cc.code AS `CC Code`,
  CAST(AVG(dcc.amount_allowed) AS decimal(10, 2)) `AVG Allowed`,
  CAST(AVG(dcc.paid_amount) AS decimal(10, 2)) `Paid Avg`,
  ii.company AS `I Company`
FROM ds
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dd
    ON ds.dd_id = dd.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ii
    ON ds.ii_id = ii.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc
    ON ds.id = dcc.dos_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cc
    ON dcc.cpt_id = cc.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN bi
    ON ds.bi_id = bi.id
WHERE ii.company = "Alpha"
AND code = '35647'
AND dcc.amount_allowed > 0
```

which returns results like

| CC Code | AVG Allowed | Paid Avg | Insurance Company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 35647 | 9373.44 | 8652.30 | Alpha |

i would like to just run it have it pass each of the codes and return the results for each code.

How would be best to go about doing this ?
Thanks for any help

Comment: LEFT JOINING tables from which you select no columns (bi) makes little sense. cs is an inner join, as is dcc.

Comment: Aggregation without `GROUP BY` with non-aggregated columns in `SELECT` is incompatible with `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`.

Comment: Will `cc.code` have duplicates? Or.. is a combination of `cc.code`+`ii.company` is considered as unique?

Comment: the cc.code in the second query will not be unique as its pulling all the rows from dcc where code matches, it then takes avg of the 2 columns listed

Comment: if i didnt have the AVG ones listed , if i had just done select cc.code, dcc.amount_allowed, dcc,paid_amount, that would return 100s of rows with data with whatever code is selected

Comment: the extra join is just because this is pared down from a larger query, i didnt remove all the extra stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to focus on what you're trying to get first. Forget all the other tables that are not used in the query; either in `SELECT` or `WHERE`. For example:

```
SELECT
  cc.code AS `CC Code`,
  CAST(AVG(dcc.amount_allowed) AS decimal(10, 2)) `AVG Allowed`,
  CAST(AVG(dcc.paid_amount) AS decimal(10, 2)) `Paid Avg`,
  ii.company AS `I Company`
FROM ds
/* comment out this part
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dd
    ON ds.dd_id = dd.id */
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ii
    ON ds.ii_id = ii.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc
    ON ds.id = dcc.dos_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cc
    ON dcc.cpt_id = cc.id
/* comment out this part
  LEFT OUTER JOIN bi
    ON ds.bi_id = bi.id*/
WHERE ii.company = "Alpha"
AND code = '35647'
AND dcc.amount_allowed > 0
```

Then based on your condition *"I would like to just run it have it pass each of the codes and return the results for each code"*, modify the query to something like this:

```
SELECT
  cc.code AS `CC Code`,
  CAST(AVG(dcc.amount_allowed) AS decimal(10, 2)) `AVG Allowed`,
  CAST(AVG(dcc.paid_amount) AS decimal(10, 2)) `Paid Avg`,
  ii.company AS `I Company`
FROM ds
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ii
    ON ds.ii_id = ii.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc
    ON ds.id = dcc.dos_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cc
    ON dcc.cpt_id = cc.id
WHERE dcc.amount_allowed > 0
GROUP BY cc.code, ii.company;

*commented out part omitted here for better view.
*removed > WHERE ii.company = "Alpha" AND code = '35647'.
```

Since you have an aggregation (`AVG()`), any non-aggregated column(s) in `SELECT` should be in the `GROUP BY`.

In case for `ii.company`, a few options:

1. If you don't want it, remove it from `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.
2. If you don't really care what `ii.company` returns, you can change it to `ANY_VALUE(ii.company)` and retain it in `GROUP BY`.
3. If you want to show everything in `ii.company` attached to a single `cc.code`, you can change to `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ii.company)` and remove it from `GROUP BY`.

See if this will work out for you.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful, the main issue i have left is my first query was to give me a specific list of codes to then check the avg allowed, paid avg, against. for those codes where the status of the claim was on hold., when i run that first query i posted it returns me about 100 claim tickets that were on hold using various cc codes, of those 100 there were 26 Distinct cc codes (a given ticket can utilize several cc codes). what i want to do is get that list of distinct codes that meet the given criteria and then have this new script show the AVGs for just those codes. thanks this is helpful

Comment: actually i figured that part out, just need to include subquery for INCLUDE statement in the WHERE clause and that returns my list of codes i need to use.  Thanks again for the help.